# Unknown or invalid 'request_id' was specified

Tags: asp.net-core, openiddict, asp.net-core-middleware

Let's say we have two applications running at https://app1.domain.com and https://app2.domain.com. When the user connects to the app they are being redirected to https://auth.domain.com for authentication, they log in and are being redirected back to app1 or app2. This is all working fine. However, often the user will favorite the app after they have reached the auth page, storing the URL like https://auth.domain.com/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%3Frequest_id%3Dzi9v5MADn2z9ePpQ245I4bPJYp1F7yX3UT2cOAPpOGs
Of course this URL works the first time but after they logged in the request_id becomes invalid and when they use the favorite they are greeted with an exception after logging in. The exception reads:

```js
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "The specified 'request_id' is invalid.",
  "error_uri": "https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2052"
}
```

This exception is being thrown by https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/blob/a812ca46711d511d1b2dd3b9c237ed85fe4cfbbe/src/OpenIddict.Server.AspNetCore/OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreHandlers.Authentication.cs#L105 It's trying to retrieve the request in the cache but it's no longer there because it's used already. I can probably redirect the user to a nicer page via middleware but is it possible to retrieve what initiated the original request so I can point them to the correct app URL?

**Update 2023-08-03**

This seems so expensive. Is there a better way?

```cs
app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/connect/authorize"), builder =>
{
  builder.Use(async (context, next) =>
  {
    var originalBody = context.Response.Body;

    try
    {
      using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
      {
        context.Response.Body = memStream;

        await next.Invoke();

        if (context.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)
        {
          memStream.Position = 0;
          var responseBody = new StreamReader(memStream).ReadToEnd();

          if (responseBody.Contains("The specified 'request_id' is invalid"))
          {
            context.Response.Redirect("/error");
          }
        }

        memStream.Position = 0;
        await memStream.CopyToAsync(originalBody);
      }

    }
    finally
    {
      context.Response.Body = originalBody;
    }
  });
});
```